# Populate data Map before opening screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get data from an API to populate a Map and then display the screen to show the data from the Map

My getter is as follows:

```
Map data = {};
Future getData(symbol) async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/" +
          symbol +
          "?apikey=${api_key}"));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    // print(jsonResponse);
    data = jsonResponse[0];
    print(data);
  }
}
```

For starters, I am trying to display the symbol and name from the data in the API:

```
void initState() {
    getData(data['symbol']);
    super.initState();
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 80,
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Symbol", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            Text("Name", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

After opening one screen successfully, on opening the next screen, I get the error:

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Can anyone suggest steps to deal with the issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few things that could have gone wrong in the code that you've provided. The `getData` function is an asynchronous function marked as `async` and needs to be inside an asynchronous context to actually work properly. What is *probably* happening in this case is that the data doesn't even have enough time to get downloaded before your widget gets loaded on the screen.

What you need to do is to use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) by having a look at the documentation and the introduction video which is in the link I've provided for you.

The `FutureBuilder` will be able to execute a `Future<T>` and inside its builder you will be able to retrieve an `AsyncSnapshot` of either your Future's data or an error.

Comment: Will I need to wrap all the widgets, even the AppBar inside a FutureBuilder then? Is there some way to show a CircularProgressIndicator while the data gets downloaded and then display the screen?

Comment: You do not need to wrap the entire app in a FutureBuilder. The "body" of your Scaffold is usually where you would consume a Future inside a FutureBuilder. Regarding the loading, yes absolutely. The AsyncSnapshot that the FutureBuilder sends to you contains various states such as "loading" in which you can display a progress indicator.

Comment: how do i render my AppBar, since I am using data from the API in the title of the AppBar as well?

Comment: if you need to render data from the api in the AppBar you need to wrap it in the future builder.

Comment: How can I give it a loading indicator before the data loads up? I'm getting the red error screen for a second after getting my desired screen.